# How can we authenticate a node via Knox

Tags: authentication, knox-gateway, apache-knox

We are looking at ways to access hadoop services via knox. But, we don't want LDAP (user-password) authentication. Instead, we would want to have our node authenticated. So, that whenever a request from our node goes , it is entertained.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "node authentication" but I am assuming you want a specific ip address / machine to be allowed access. Knox has two main ways to [authenticate](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-13-0/user-guide.html#Authentication), using

1. Authentication Providers (e.g. LDAP, PAM etc.)
2. Federation Providers (e.. SSO)

Other than LDAP, knox provides many other ways of authentication, for e.g.

1. [PAM](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-13-0/user-guide.html#PAM+based+Authentication)
2. [Hadoop Auth](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-13-0/user-guide.html#HadoopAuth+Authentication+Provider)
3. [Knox SSO](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-13-0/user-guide.html#KnoxSSO+Setup+and+Configuration)
4. Basic Auth, not really recommended

You might also be interested in [Knox Authorization](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-13-0/user-guide.html#KnoxSSO+Setup+and+Configuration) provider which will allow you to grant access to requests from only whitelisted ip addresses and/or users, groups etc.